# What libraries exist for fast sprite rendering in Silverlight that work across all platforms

Tags: silverlight, graphics, sprite, silverlight-5.0, game-engine

The question is what libraries if any exist for rendering fast sprite graphics like in a game. That would include rendering tiled backgrounds (pixel accurate positioning and size), drawing character sprites (transparency key or alpha blending) and ideally rotation as well.

The obvious answer was XNA which is a part of Silverlight as of version 5 but it isn't actually supported across all platforms - apparently it only works on Windows and not Mac because it utilizes DirectX. What alternatives to XNA exist for cross platform Silverlight games?

Comment: I wasn't aware that *silverlight* worked on all platforms.